# Azure DocumentDB Database/Collection limits

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

What is the limit on the amount of collections a single database on DocumentDB can have? I keep landing on this link for general DocumentDB limits, but nothing on here goes into that detail:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-limits

I may need up to 200 collections running on 1 DocumentDB database at a given time. This is to partition customer data by collection. If this is not possible then I'll have to partition across multiple databases but I can't find the information I need to figure out the proper partitioning strategy!

Also, do I get charged for empty databases, or not until the first collection is created?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for billing support (free to open a ticket). They would be the best people to talk about quota and increases with. But... a quota-limit question isn't a programming question.

Comment: `Also, do I get charged for empty databases, or not until the first collection is created?` - No you don't get charged for empty databases. Only for the collections you create inside a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit to the number of collections (no practical limit anyway), which is why it's not listed in the limits page. To provision for example, 200 collections or more, you have to contact [billing support](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/documentdb/documentdb-increase-limits).

Empty databases are **not** charged in DocumentDB.